# How to make the contents of a custom view match its size when the parent has initial scale of 0?

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-canvas

Im developing an Android game and I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for some time now.

I have a custom view and I have overrided its `onDraw` and `onMeasure`. This custom view is inside either a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <com.leftcorner.craftersofwar.images.BitmapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem is, that in the `onMeasure` function the parent has a size of 0. The only thing I can do is to scale my view according to the desired content size. However, if the bitmap is larger than the final size of the view, this will result in a misplaced canvas when I enter the `onDraw` function. The (0, 0) coordinates of the canvas are somewhere over the edge of the view itself.

I can get the parent size just before drawing with `((View) this.getParent()).getWidth();`, compare the bitmap size to it and draw the bitmap in the correct scale, but drawing it to the canvas fails as the bitmap is out of the view bounds in a location unknown to me.

So, how could I draw this bitmap of mine to the canvas so that it would actually be visible? It would be better if it was also centered in the view.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    pWidth = ((View) this.getParent()).getWidth();
    pHeight = ((View) this.getParent()).getHeight();

    fWidth = Utility.smaller(pWidth, bWidth);
    fHeight = Utility.smaller(pHeight, bHeight);

    if(bitmap != null){
        // As you can see, I'm not using a custom bitmap class.
        // This function draws the bitmap to the canvas.
        // (x, y, width, height, canvas)
        bitmap.getStorageBitmap().drawScaledBitmap(0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, canvas);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    bWidth = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    bHeight = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight() * scale);

    if(bitmap != null) setMeasuredDimension(bWidth, bHeight);
    else setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dimension of the parent you can do as follows:

```
    // set the id of your LinearLayout to parentLayout
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    final ViewTreeObserver observer = parent.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            parent.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            int parentHeight = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
            int parentWidth = parent.getMeasuredWidth();

            // set dimensions to bitmap
            bitmap.getLayoutParams().height = parentHeight * scale;
            bitmap.getLayoutParams().width= parentWidth * scale;
            bitmap.requestLayout();

            ViewTreeObserver obs = parent.getViewTreeObserver();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can put this code directly in onCreate

Comment: I use my custom view several times so the function has to be inside it, which means that I can't call anything in onCreate. In addition, I already mentioned that I can get the parent dimensions with ((View) this.getParent()).getWidth() but even after resizing the view with getLayoutParams().width = pWidth; the canvas coordinates still seem to be weird.

Comment: And the problem persists if using RelativeLayout? (thinking that the weight of LinearLayout might cause the strange behaviour). Another possibility would be to use FrameLayout as the root of your layout (not just the container of the bitmap). This way you can add the bitmap directly on top of whatever other layouts you may have on the display.

Comment: You're right. The LinearLayout weight is the guilty one and checking if the parent is an instance of LinearLayout isn't much of a problem so my previous argument was bad. I apologize that I didn't think it through.

I'm close to solving this issue in my own way. My solution differs a lot from yours, but the basic idea is the same: post the layout size calculations. I calculate everything in onMeasure and in the onDraw I check if the width or height is close to 0. If yes, I will call requestLayout instead of drawing the bitmap.

Comment: I will add my own solution as an answer when I have cleared the smaller bugs from it, but I will accept your answer as the correct one as it is basically correct.

Comment: My own solution is below. It's the same thing done in a very different way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by cYrixmorten is correct, but I solved this issue in a bit different way. Please note that the height of my LinearLayout was set to wrap_content but the width of it comes from the weight.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(getWidth() < 1 || getHeight() < 1){
        requestLayout();
    } else if(bitmap != null){
        bitmap.getStorageBitmap().drawScaledBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), canvas);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(bitmap != null) {
        bitmapWidth = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
        bitmapHeight = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
        return;
    }

    parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    if(parentWidth < bitmapWidth){
        bitmapHeight = bitmapHeight * parentWidth / bitmapWidth;
        bitmapWidth = parentWidth;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
}
```